# FrameLayout stealing TextView's touch event

Tags: android, events, textview, touch

I have this simple code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public TextView textView;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.touch_textView);
    textView.setText("Hello");


    textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        String TAG = "onTouchListener";

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Triggered");

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(event.getAction())
            {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d(TAG,"Down");
                builder.append("down, ");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                builder.append("move, ");
                Log.d(TAG,"Move");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                builder.append("cancel, ");
                Log.d(TAG,"Cancel");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                builder.append("up, ");
                Log.d(TAG,"Up");
                break;
            }

            builder.append(event.getX());
            builder.append(", ");
            builder.append(event.getY());
            String text = builder.toString();
            Log.d("TouchTest", text);
            textView.setText(text);         
            return true;
        }
    });
}
}
```

...and this simple layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.touchhandling.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/touch_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is that my TextView's onTouchListener is not receiving the touch events, instead I see this in Logcat:

ViewRoot's Touch event: ACTION_UP

It seems that my FrameLayout is stealing the touch events. How can I make this work? Should the child get the event first?

Thank you, any hint is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try `textView.setClickable(true)`.

Comment: Nope, still the same behaviour. If I do the following:

TextView textView = new TextView();
textView.setOnTouchListener(
    ...
);
setContentView(textView);
...then the listener works fine. Problem is cause when I use a layout, that is why I am suspecting that the problem is with the textView's root.

Comment: I tried your code quickly in an ActionBarActivity and it's working for me. Are you doing anything else in the activity? The xml posted is actually the R.layout.activity_main?

Comment: That is all I'm doing. I have pasted the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestMainActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    public TextView textView;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        context = this;
        if (savedInstanceState == null)
        {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment
    {
        public TextView textView;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        Context context;

        public PlaceholderFragment()
        {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            context = this.getActivity();
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.touch_textView);
            textView.setText("Hello");

            // context = this;
            textView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
            {

                String TAG = "onTouchListener";

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Triggered");

                    Toast.makeText(context, "Triggered textView", "Triggered textView".length()).show();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch (event.getAction())
                    {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            Log.d(TAG, "Down");
                            builder.append("down, ");

                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            builder.append("move, ");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Move");
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                            builder.append("cancel, ");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Cancel");
                            break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                            builder.append("up, ");
                            Log.d(TAG, "Up");
                            break;
                    }

                    builder.append(event.getX());
                    builder.append(", ");
                    builder.append(event.getY());
                    String text = builder.toString();
                    Log.d("TouchTest", text);
                    textView.setText(text);
                    return true;
                }
            });

            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

And the fragment_layout.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:id="@+id/touch_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.stacktest.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/touch_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've tried with your code and it behaves just like mine. Strange, how could we have two different behaviours....What is your min. SDK? Mine is 11 (Honeycomb), but since you are using getSupportFragmentManager I assume that you use a lower minSdk?! Could this be the source of the difference...?